Tabulator problem sorting with groupedvalues
i have datas grouped by 'groupname' key... when sorting with header button on another key i want to sort inside groups but don't want the groups to be sorted. I try several things like resorting the values by group in the corresponding events (datasorted, datasortin but nothing seems to work ...) any idea on how to implement this ?
I managed to do this in older versions like this
 dataSorted: function (datas, sortList, dir, ctx, activedata) {

   //    console.log(datas);
   if (sortList[0] && sortList[0].field.field != "GroupName") {
     groups = _.groupBy(activedata, 'GroupName');
     groups = _.sortBy(groups, function (grp) {

       return grp[0].GroupName
     });
     var result = [];
     //   var vehics = Object.values(groups);
     var vehics = Object.keys(groups).map(function (e) {
       return groups[e]
     });
     for (var i = 0; i < vehics.length; i++) {
       for (var j = 0; j < vehics[i].length; j++) {
         result.push(vehics[i][j]);
       }
     }
     //     activedata = result;
     //ctx.data = datas;
     ctx.activeData = result;
   }

but can't manage to do this in newest versions ....
